# Codeigniter file upload error

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am developing a tender management system and trying to attach the pdf file during the tender creation.

I have following controller and view, it is showing me some sort like no file is choosen. It is killing me.

```
function addtender() {
    $this->form->set_rules('name', 'Tender Name', 'required|min_length[4]');
    $this->form->set_rules('district', 'District Name', 'required|min_length[4]');
    $this->form->set_rules('department', 'Department Name', 'required|min_length[4]');
    $this->form->set_rules('userfile', 'Pdf File ', 'required');
    if($this->form->run()) {
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/pdf/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $config['max_size']    = 1000;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
         $this->data['page_data'] = 'admin/upload_view';
     }
    else
    {
          print_r($this->upload->data());
    }
    }
}
```

I have this controller code to upload pdf file codeignitor.
My view is

```
    <div class="col-md-10">
<h3>Add Tenders</h3>
    <?=validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');?>
    <?=form_open(site_url('admin/addtender'))?>
    <label>Tender Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text">
    <label>District</label>
    <input type="text" name="district" class="form-control">
    <label>Department</label>
    <input type="text" name="department" class="form-control">
    <label>PDF file</label>
    <input type="file" name="userfile" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Tender">
</div>
```

It is saying that, You did not select a file to upload.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

**place file upload code in  form**

Answer (score 0):

U have to make form multipart/form-data